# Varchar to date Conversion

Tags: sql, date, data-conversion

Issue converting dates. Some are formatted mdyyyy while some are mmddyyyy and stored as varchar. Does anyone know my best options to convert these to date formats?

Comment: We need more informations...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How would your table display 2019-01-25 and 2019-12-05? Following your format of mdyyyy they would both come out 1252019.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @date1 varchar(8) = '872019',@date2 varchar(8) = '08122019'

Select 
@date1 as date1,
CASE 
WHEN LEN(@date1) < 8 
THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@date1,3,4)
        + REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(SUBSTRING(@date1,1,1))) + SUBSTRING(@date1,1,1) 
        + REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(SUBSTRING(@date1,2,1))) + SUBSTRING(@date1,2,1) AS DATE)
ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@date1,5,4)+SUBSTRING(@date1,1,2)+SUBSTRING(@date1,3,2) as date) END as casted_date1,
@date2 as date2,
cast(substring(@date2,5,4)+substring(@date2,1,2)+SUBSTRING(@date2,3,2) as date) as casted_date2
```